# Can't install FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony4, symfony-security

I cannot install the `FOSUserBundle`.

I configured `config/config.yml` as follows:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm          # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: App\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
```

But when I run this command:

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0"
```

I get the error:

```
The child node "db_driver" at path "fos_user" must be configured
```

Any hints why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

All of this config information should not be stored in `config/config.yml` in Symfony 4 (in Symfony 3, this would be correct). Instead, you have to create a config file `config/packages/fos_user.yaml` and save this information there. You then can remove `config/config.yml`.

Comment: To be honest , I tried another solution for (other than the FOSUserBundle),but I will keep that in mind for my next projects, this i absolutely interesting note!! big big thanks Dirk !!